# The annihilating ideals of a ring R is again an ideal of that particular ring R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

A nonzero ideal $I$ is called an annihilating ideal of a ring R if there exists a nonzero proper ideal $J$ such that $IJ = (0)$.
I want to know my above question is correct or not.

Comment: Are you considering only commutative rings? Are you using the word "collection" in sense of "union"? That's because a collection of subsets of $R$ is a family of sets, not a subset.

Comment: @G.Elo The collection of all annihilating ideals is a set of **subsets** of $R$, not a set of **elments** of $R$.

Comment: When you post a question, write the question in the body, too. Going to vote to close as 'unclear what you're asking' unless you clarify soon. Of course, if you really are asking if a set of subsets of a set is a subset of the set, that's a different matter.